# Java grails: Cannot cast object 'Mon Feb 12 00:00:00 PKT 2018' with class 'java.util.Date' to class 'org.joda.time.LocalDate'

Tags: java, date, grails, groovy

I am having an issue with grails new SimpleDateFormat.

As I am receiving date time formatted data from the other server via APIs, so I am trying to convert string to datetime with SimpleDateTimeFormat,

I am getting the following error while saving in data in database, please have a look code below

**Error:**

```
Cannot cast object 'Mon Feb 12 00:00:00 PKT 2018' with class 'java.util.Date' to class 'org.joda.time.LocalDate'
```

**Domain class**

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate

LocalDate startDate
```

**Code:**

```
def pattern = "yyy-MM-dd"
        def startDateStr = [pathtofield].Value
        def stringToDate = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(startDateStr)

[domainclass].startDate = stringToDate
```

Please help.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat.parse` returns a `java.util.Date`, not an `org.joda.time.LocalDate`. Use the appropriate format from Jodatime instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    
    def startDateStr = "2018-02-12 00:00:00"
    def stringToDate = formatter.parseLocalDate(startDateStr)
    
    [domainclass].startDate = stringToDate
```

I have run the code corresponding Java code and hand translated without knowing grails, please forgive any error I may have made. In any case `formatter.parseLocalDate()` gives you a Joda-Time `LocalDate`, and I understand from your error message that this is what you need.

For a formatter don't consider `SimpleDateFormat`. One, it's a notorious troublemaker of a class, two, it doesn't work with the Joda-Time classes. As Mark Rotteveel said in a comment, Joda-Time has got its own `DateTimeFormatter` class for parsing and formatting its date and time objects.

Comment: Thanks Ole, but when I am trying to acheive this on your way, I am getting the following error `Invalid format: "2018-02-12 00:00:00" is malformed at " 00:00:00"`

Comment: @MuhammadOwais It would have been better if you had told us the format of your string from the outset, I had understood from your question that it was `yyy-MM-dd`, and my answer was correct under that condition. I have now edited to fit your `2018-02-12 00:00:00`.